# Transfer function of an electromechanical system

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function

In this exercise I am asked to find θc(s)/θR(s), of which I am given the following indications.

In the system shown in the figure, the motor is an armature-controlled dc motor, and there is also a gear train (N1/N2=n) coupling motor and load.  The reference input is θR and the output is the angular position θc, which is proportional by a factor n with the angular displacement of the motor.  Consider initial conditions equal to zero and determine the transfer function θc(s)/θR(s).

[image]

And I get the following equations.

Ra = Armature resistance - La = Armature inductance

ia = Armature current - if = Field current (constant)

Vb= Voltage applied to the armature - Vc = f.c.e.m

θm = Angular displacement of the motor shaft  - τm = Torque developed by the motor

Jeq = Moment of inertia motor-load - Jm = Moment of inertia of the motor

JL = Moment of inertia of the load -feq = Coefficient of friction motor-load

fm = Coefficient of friction of the motor - fL = Coefficient of friction of the load

[image]

Of which I just took the following and added one or two and tried but I don't know what to do with theta m, plus I don't think they are the right equations.

\begin{array}{l}\left[1\right]\ Va\left(s\right)=K_s\left(\theta _R\left(s\right)-\theta _C\left(s\right)\right)\\
\left[2\right]\ Vb\left(s\right)=Va\left(s\right)K_p\\
\left[3\right]\ Vb\left(s\right)=Ia\left(s\right)\left(R_a+sLa\right)+V_c\left(s\right)\\
\left[4\right]\ T_m\left(s\right)=K_AIa\left(s\right)\ \\
\left[5\right]\ T_m\left(s\right)=\theta _m\left(s\right)\left(s^2J_{eq}+sf_{eq}\right)\ \\
\left[6\right]\ Vc\left(s\right)=K_b\theta _m\left(s\right)\\
Substituting\\
Ia\left(s\right)=\frac{\theta _m\left(s\right)}{K_A}\left(s^2J_{eq}+sf_{eq}\right)\\
Vb\left(s\right)=\frac{\theta _m\left(s\right)}{K_A}\left(s^2J_{eq}+sf_{eq}\right)\left(R_a+sLa\right)+K_b\theta _m\left(s\right)\\
Va\left(s\right)=\theta _m\left(s\right)\left[\left(\frac{s^2J_{eq}+sf_{eq}}{K_AK_p}\right)\left(R_a+sLa\right)+\frac{K_b}{K_AK_p}\right]\\
\theta _m\left(s\right)\left[\left(\frac{s^2J_{eq}+sf_{eq}}{K_AK_p}\right)\left(R_a+sLa\right)+\frac{K_b}{K_AK_p}\right]=K_s\left(\theta _R\left(s\right)-\theta _C\left(s\right)\right)\end{array}

After that point I don't know what to do
I just want to know if the equations I took are correct or not, after that an indication of how would be the best way to clear for the question, please thank you very much, this is very confusing for me.